# Splitting IF statement in multiple lines in VBScript

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I was wondering if in VBScript I can break a `If` statement in multiple lines. Like:

```
If (UCase(Trim(objSheet.Cells(i, a).Value)) = "YES") Or _
(UCase(Trim(objSheet.Cells(i, b).Value)) = "NO") Then

' Do something

End If
```

I tried this and got a syntax error as `If` expects a `Then` in the same line.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes you can break IF statement in multiple lines in vbscript. Here is a very basic example

```
If 1 = 1 Or _
2 = 2 Then

wscript.echo "See, It Works :)"

End If
```

or

```
If (UCase(Trim("1")) = "1") Or _
(UCase(Trim("2")) = "2") Then

wscript.echo "See, It Works :)"

End If
```

The error is somewhere else. Check your workbook objects and their values. Also check the values of `i`, `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, line breaks in if statements are supported.

I ran the following code both in Excel/VBA and as a single vbscript and it worked without throwing an error.

```
Dim aStr
aStr = "yeah"

If (UCase(Trim(aStr)) = "YES") Or _
   (UCase(Trim(aStr)) = "NO") Then
  MsgBox "yes/no"
Else
  MsgBox "no action"
End If
```

Or is it a problem with objSheet? Did you try to set a variable for `UCase(Trim(objSheet.Cells(i, a).Value)`? Did it show the expected Value?

Comment: Thanks. It is working now. Sorry! accepted the other answer as you were 6 mins late :P